# How do I compare two listboxes?

Tags: vb.net, listbox, comparison

I have two listboxes (1: Primary, 2:Secondary).
These listboxes contain numbers. The Primary Listbox contains 7 numbers, and the Secondary Listbox contains 6 numbers.

[image]

I want to compare the values of the Primary Listbox to those of the Secondary.
This comparison should yield three results:

**Result #1:** 
X number of values were found to be common.

[image]

**Result#2:**
All numbers matched.

[image]

**Result#3:**
No matches found.

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
If lstPrimaryNumbers.Items.Count = 0 Or lstSecondaryNumbers.Items.Count = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("There is nothing to compare.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        End If

        For i As Integer = 0 To lstPrimaryNumbers.Items.Contains
            For j As Integer = 0 To lstSecondaryNumbers.Items.Contains

                If i = j Then
                    MessageBox.Show(i & " " & j & " matched!")
                End If
            Next
        Next
```

**PLEASE NOTE:**

**I HAVE CHANGED MY ENTIRE INTERFACE, SO THIS POST IS OBSOLETE AND I HAVE NO USE FOR IT NOW. THANK YOU EVERYONE FOR YOUR SUPPORT!**

**I will leave this for the moderators to decide whether to remove this post or keep it for other users reference.**

**I will flag this post.**

Comment: Just add all matches to a [**`List(Of T)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) and check it afterwards. If `Count = 0` then no match was found.

Comment: Also, I doubt this compiles: `To lstPrimaryNumbers.Items.Contains`. Did you mean `Items.Count`?

Comment: Yes. @VisualVincent I presumed the .Contains would retrieve the values of the listbox. I`ll try the List(of T).

Comment: Reading the description that IntelliSense shows you when either hovering over the method or selecting it in the member list while typing can save you a lot of trouble in the future. :)

Comment: @VisualVincent Thanks! I`ll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2):

The matching items could be found with

```
Dim r = lb1.Items.Cast(Of Int32).Where(Function (x) lb2.Items.Contains(x))
MessageBox.Show(String.Join(",", r) & " matched")
```

If you want to have a full match, then use IEnumerable.All to check

```
Dim a = lb1.Items.Cast(Of Int32).All(Function (x) lb2.Items.Contains(x))
If a Then
   MessageBox.Show("Full Match")
End If
```

Finally if you want only know if some items match then use IEnumerable.Any

```
Dim b = lb1.Items.Cast(Of Int32).Any(Function(x) lb2.Items.Contains(x))
If Not b Then
    MessageBox.Show("No matches where found")
End If
```

I have assumed that your items are integers, but if you add them as strings then you need to change the *Cast(Of Int32)* to *Cast(Of String)*

Comment: I tried all three. It gives back an error stating that the cast is not valid. My listbox values are integers, so I didn`t change anything in the cast, just kept Int32.  Strangely enough, I used the Cast(Of String), it worked, but it didn`t give me the results I want. I tried it, and visually, there was one match. It returned saying that no matches were found.

Comment: @me.user  Have you checked whether, by chance, there's a white space or a non-printable character somewhere? Have you inserted those values manually? Copy/Paste?

Comment: @Jimi The numbers in the Secondary listbox are generated by a click event. These generated numbers are firstly placed in a different listbox. Then by this click event, I transfer these numbers to the Secondary listbox.

Comment: @me.user So, the question extends/transfers to the source ListBox and/or the copy method.

Comment: @Jimi Yes exactly. My entire programs entails generating random numbers. In the source listbox, it gets populated with random numbers via a Generate click event. After that, I use a checkbox to transfer these generated numbers to the Secondary Listbox. I only need to compare the values between the Primary and Listboxes, as inquired in my post above.

Comment: @me.user  There also the chance (Steve wrote a note about it) that your ListBoxes contain different types. If you have inserted some, for example, as strings in one list and as integer in another, you have to convert one of the values before using Compare. Something like: `Dim r = lb1.Items.Cast(Of String).Where(Function (x) lb2.Items.Contains(CInt(x)))`

Comment: @me.user You should add the code that transfers items between these listboxes.  Tested both with numbers and with strings and removed the Not in from of the test for the a variable but it works as expected

Answer (score 1):

First, I got the contents of the ListBoxes into arrays with a little linq. Then using the .Intersect method found the matches. And displayed the .Count. You iterate the result with a For Each

```
Private Sub OPCode()
        Dim id1() As Integer = (From i In ListBox1.Items Select CInt(i)).ToArray
        Dim id2() As Integer = (From i In ListBox2.Items Select CInt(i)).ToArray
        Dim Matches As IEnumerable(Of Integer) = id1.Intersect(id2)
        MessageBox.Show(Matches.Count.ToString)
    End Sub
'TextBox1.Multiline = True is set at design time
'Expand the text box size so several lines will be visible
 For Each Match As Integer In Matches
      TextBox1.Text &= (CStr(Match) & Environment.NewLine)
 Next
```

Comment: That worked! Now I know how many matches I`m getting, but I also wanted the matches to be displayed. For example, if 2 matches were found, I require these two numbers to be displayed, comma delimited.

Comment: I have edited my answer to show the Matches in a text box.